# Origin of OmniAuth - Where was /auth/facebook called from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request, omniauth

I'm using OmniAuth as a way to let users link their social networks into a system.  So I have the common match `'/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'authentications#create'` in my routes.

This is fine, and I store that info for a particular user in a table.  However, I have another way of using OmniAuth that should not overlap this one.  The users can use a call to /auth/facebook to log into the system and therefore I should not just store that information into the authentications table, but also log the user into the system.

On the other hand, a user that is logged in might just want to link his/her Facebook account without logging in but the call will be done to the same `/auth/facebook`.  So my question is: How can I discover where that call to `auth/facebook` was done from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea would be to have a `before_filter` in your authentications controller, which simply checks if the user is already signed-in. `#sign_in?` might look something like this:

```
def sign_in?
 if @oauth.provider == 'facebook'
   if current_user?
     # then lets associate this facebook credentials with the logged-in user.
   else
     # user isn't logged in, so let's do that
     sign_in(@authentication.account)
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: this is a good idea. the only thing here is that I deal with Facebook sign up in another action of another controller. I will see.